# Connect to Remote Desktop using a different network interface

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop, ethernet, windows-server

My computer has two NICs, each one connects to a different network. The primary one is the gateway 192.168.1.1 that receives one internet connection. The second one is a WiFi Adapter that is connected to ANOTHER network, and that Wireless Connection has a Windows Server 2019 connected to it. The gateway is 192.168.31.254.

When i need to connect to Windows Server 2019 i have to DEACTIVATE the Ethernet adapter and leave only the WiFi on... Then i am able to connect to the server. But then if both of them are enabled when i connect via Remote Desktop Connection it uses the Ethernet adapter as default and i get the error message:

```
Error code: 0x516 
Extended error code: 0x0 
Activity Id: ID {9ed47227-be64-436e-ac2f-d85f30fe0000}
```

How can i connect to my server using the gateway wireless instead of using the ethernet gateway? I would like to access without needing to deactivate the Ethernet Adapter every time.

Its very annoying... Can someone help me?

Edit - Output of route print

```
Tabela de rotas IPv4
===========================================================================
Rotas ativas:
Endereço de rede          Máscara   Ender. gateway       Interface   Custo
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         25.0.0.1    192.168.137.1   9256
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   192.168.31.254    192.168.31.86     50
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.100     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0      No vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255      No vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      No vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0      No vínculo     192.168.1.100    281
    192.168.1.100  255.255.255.255      No vínculo     192.168.1.100    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255      No vínculo     192.168.1.100    281
     192.168.31.0    255.255.255.0      No vínculo     192.168.31.86    306
    192.168.31.86  255.255.255.255      No vínculo     192.168.31.86    306
   192.168.31.255  255.255.255.255      No vínculo     192.168.31.86    306
    192.168.137.0    255.255.255.0      No vínculo     192.168.137.1   9256
    192.168.137.1  255.255.255.255      No vínculo     192.168.137.1   9256
  192.168.137.255  255.255.255.255      No vínculo     192.168.137.1   9256
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      No vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      No vínculo     192.168.137.1   9256
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      No vínculo     192.168.31.86    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      No vínculo     192.168.1.100    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      No vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      No vínculo     192.168.137.1   9256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      No vínculo     192.168.31.86    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      No vínculo     192.168.1.100    281
===========================================================================
```

Comment: Can you please print the routing table? Ie, running `route print` in cmd.exe. I'm right to assume that your client is also a windows PC (not just the server)?

Comment: Does it help to create a host-name for the Windows Server 2019 server in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, adding a line like `myserver  192.168.31.x`, where `x` is used by the server?

Comment: Hey @harrymc 
You mean in the hosts file of my computer or the hosts file of Windows Server?

Comment: @jvda I edited my question with the route print command output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line, if you type

```
mstsc /?
```

it will list a whole bunch of options.  mstsc is the command line name for remote desktop (Microsoft Terminal Server Client).  The ones you are interested in are /v and /g.  So if you wish to connect to soci it would be

```
mstsc /v:soci /g:192.168.31.254
```

Comment: Hi. That command actually makes me try to connect to 192.168.31.254
I dont want to connect to that IP. That IP is the gateway of my modem

I want to connect to a server that is connected to the same SUBNET of 192.168.31.254

Comment: So what is the IP of the windows server?

Comment: Use the address of your wireless server in the /g

Comment: @jvda W Server is 192.168.31.25.

Comment: @cup Ill try this right now and mark as solved if it works! Bro, thanks.

Comment: And the /v i use the Windows server IP? mstsc /v:srv-example /g:mywifigateway... ?

Comment: Yeah, i think thats the command but i just got a weird 'certificate is not safe' error and couldnt connect...

Comment: "This computer cant verify the identity of gateway 192.168.31.254" 

Comment: This is something to do with the security certificate.  There are all sorts of solutions to _certificate is not safe_ .   Just do a search for it on the internet.